# MDX - Multiple Where and/or Filter Conditions

Tags: sql, filter, mdx, olap

I apologize beforehand for a seemingly basic MDX question.  I am trying to filter an MDX resultset based on multiple combinations of dimension attributes.

This is my dimension/measures layout:

Dimensions:

```
[AccidentDate]
Year
Quarter
Month
Day
Date

[ItemInformation] 
ItemState

[CoverageInformation] 
CoverageHiearchy
----UserLine
--- Coverage Code
```

Measures:

```
CTDPaid
```

Now, I wish to select the total amount from the `[CTDPaid]` measure, grouped by the `[ItemInformation].ItemState` attribute.  However, I would like to filter the resultset of this query based on multiple filter conditions.

These conditions would be the following, and would be evaluated **separately**:

```
1. [CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[002] and [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[MI]
2. [CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[004] and [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[MI]
3. [CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[004] and [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[IL]
4. [CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[002] and [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[IL]
```

Essentially, if I were to port this over to a T-SQL where condition, it would constitute the following:

where

```
  (ItemState = 'MI' and CoverageCode = '002' and UserLine = '98')
```

and

```
  (ItemState = 'MI' and CoverageCode = '004' and UserLine = '98')
```

and

```
  (ItemState = 'IL' and CoverageCode = '002' and UserLine = '98')
```

and

```
  (ItemState = 'IL' and CoverageCode = '004' and UserLine = '98')
```

Putting this into an MDX slicer would not function as I believe cross joins across the same hierarchy are not supported.

Using the filter() MDX function is not working for me either.

I would greatly appreciate assistance with formulating the correct MDX query to correctly filter my resultset as outlined above.

Thank you kindly for your time

Comment: Can a CTDPaid be in 'MI' and 'IL' state at same time? If not your query have not results because your condition is `ItemState = 'MI' and ItemState = 'LI'`

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT 
     {...} On Columns,
     {...} On Rows
FROM  (Select 
{([CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[002], [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[MI]),
 ([CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[004], [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[MI])
 ([CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[004], [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[IL])
 ([CoverageInformation].[CoverageHiearchy].&[98]&[002], [ItemInformation].ItemState.&[IL])} On Columns
From [CubeName])
```